# Mutual information between standard gaussian and bernoulli distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, mutual-information

I have a random variable which is distribuited as a multinomial standard gaussian $z\sim N^d(0, I)$, and another r.v. that instead is distribuited as a bernoulli $\alpha \sim Bern(\pi)$. Is it possible to compute the mutual information analytically? If yes, can you show me all the steps to the results?